# The phrase "one-to-one correspondence" in a theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am starting to read something that is related to Pick functions. There are some theorems that uses the phrase "... a one-to-one correspondence between..", and I am not sure what it exactly means. For example, a theorem (due to Herglotz, Riesz) says

> The formula
> \begin{equation*}
> f(z)=i\beta+\int_{\mathbb{T}}\frac{s+z}{s-z}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s),\quad z\in \mathbb{D}.
> \end{equation*}
> establishes a one-to-one correspondence between functions $f\in \mathcal{H}$ and pairs $(\beta,\mu)\in \mathbb{R}\times M^+(\mathbb{T})$.

---

The way I understand it is

> For each $f\in \mathcal{H}$, there exist (unique?) $(\beta,\mu)\in \mathbb{R}\times M^+(\mathbb{T})$ such that
> \begin{equation*}
> f(z)=i\beta+\int_{\mathbb{T}}\frac{s+z}{s-z}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s),\quad z\in \mathbb{D}.
> \end{equation*}
> Conversely, any function $f$ of this form belongs to $\mathcal{H}$.

Is it correctly understood? I am not sure if there should be "unique" added. (BTW: I do not know what I should tag this as ...)

Comment: Your understanding is correct. This is sometimes called a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).

Comment: @angryavian Okay, I just edited the post. There should be "unique" added, right? Just to make sure

Comment: Yes, "unique" should be there.

Comment: Yes, @James.  Unique should stay.

Comment: @angryavian  Double reinforcement!!

Comment: A function $f\colon X\to Y$ is "one-to-one" (an injection) if $x_1\neq x_2$ implies $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$, which can be read as "for one output there is only one input", whereas for a function that is not one-to-one, like $x^2-1$, for output $0$ there are two inputs $1$ and $-1$. Sometimes these are called "many-to-one". The "correspondence" part refers to the property that to each $y\in Y$ there is a corresponding $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. So in a "one-to-one correspondence" for every $y\in Y$ there is a unique $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.